# Different software binary being executed on Jenkins for the same path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have installed gems binary at two places on my jenkins server, each is  different version:

```
[myserver]$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem --version
2.4.1
[myserver]$ /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem --version
2.4.4
```

I am running a job on this jenkins server with following command :  `/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem inabox`

and I get an error saying :

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command inabox
```

However when i run the same command from the command line , it identifies the `inabox` option.

To debug , when I ran this command `/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem help commands` from the console and command line the options available are different and the console output doesnt include `"inabox"` option.

To make sure that I use the correct binary , I have also exported the binary path : `PATH=$PATH:/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin` in the job , but that also doesnt solve any thing.
I suspect that for some reason , `/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem` binary is getting executed instead of `/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem` , but I am not sure how and how do I solve it. Any pointers?

**EDIT1**
Here is output of echo $PATH[image]

Here is the output of the command when I run through Jenkins console : `/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem help commands`

[image]

Here is the output of the command when I run through command line :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We identified that a GEM_PATH variable being injected into the Jenkins job was causing the gem command to not work as intended. To resolve the issue, we added the “unset GEM_PATH” line to the beginning of the shell portion of the Build steps. This allowed the gem command to again recognize the “inabox” option and successfully upload gems to the Ruby Gems server.

Answer (score 0):

1) Restart Jenkins every time you make changes to environment variables

2) if jenkins is executing the code on a slave, you need to define the PATH in your Jenkins settings.

Comment: Thankou for the answer, i had restarted the seever too, but still the same problem. I am not running this code on a slave.

Comment: @IshuGupta i opened my linux version of jenkins and tried the same thing with different binaries. I'm not quite sure to be honest because i don't have this issue. Do `echo $PATH` and update your post with the result of that please.